# Does ((dword *) v16 + 6), mean 6 bytes from v16, or 6 dwords from v16?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

In C++, when I see a location like `((dword *) v16 + 6)`, does that mean to move 6 bytes from `v16` and return as a `dword`, or move 6 `dword`s from `v16`?

I'm trying to read some pseudo-decompiled code and map the memory structures, but as those are two very different locations, I'd like to fill in this gap of my knowledge of memory structures.

Comment: depends also on where `v16` points to. Into an array?

Comment: `((dword *) v16 + 6)` is 6 `dword`s and `((dword *)(v16 + 6))` would be 6 added to `v16`, so would depends on the type of  `v16` .  Please post a [mcve] if you need a more complete answer.

Comment: `(dword *)v16` treats `v16` as an address in memory, and converts it into a pointer to a `dword`.   `((dword *) v16 + 6)` assumes that address points at the first element of an array of (at least) seven `dword`s, and gives the address of the 7th element (since array indexing in C++ is zero based, the first element in an array has index zero).   So, no, it doesn't move 6 bytes.  It moves 6 `dword`s  (a `dword` is typically represented by more than one byte).

Comment: TBH if you're still learning to program and have problems with simple expression like this, then "trying to read some pseudo-decompiled code" is likely still beyond your skill level.

Comment: Thank you @Peter. Can you copy that as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: @MSalters I would love to be steered towards documentation on how to read raw memory instructions like this. My search has been unsuccessful.

Comment: @Drazisil: It's not a "raw memory instruction". That's another part of your skill issue. This is very basic C++. Yes, the decompiler could have decompiled it further to `dword* v16_dw = (dword*) v16; foo(v16_dw[6]);`. But the target audience for the decompiler would dislike that; they prefer the succinct expression.

Comment: If `v16` is `dword v16[3];`, then `v16 + 6` would mean **undefined behavior**.  A lot depends on the context, which was not provided.

Comment: @Peter "At least seven `dword`s" is overconstraining it. It can be as small as 6 elements, as pointing to the one-after-the-last element is a perfectly legal way to represent the end of a container. As long as this pointer is not dereferenced.

Comment: @Mestkon - Yeah, true.   Although I'm concerned that is probably one step of detail too far, given the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To hopefully help understand the meaning, I'll break it into parts

`(dword *)v16` treats the value of `v16` as an address in memory, and converts it into a pointer to a `dword`.

`((dword *) v16 + 6)` assumes that the address given by `(dword *)v16` points at the first element of an array of (at least) six `dwords`, and gives a pointer who's value is the address of the 7th element (since array indexing in C++ is zero based, the first element in an array has index zero) or, for a vector with six elements, pointing "one past the end".

So, no, adding `6` does doesn't move 6 bytes. It moves 6 `dword`s (a `dword` is not a standard type in C++ but, where it is used/defined as a type, it is typically represented by more than one byte).

That is consistent with how pointer arithmetic works in C++  (the size of what is pointed at - in this case a `dword` - is considered when adding an integral value to a pointer).